# Pointer to pointer comparision breaks when while(1) removed - why?

Tags: c++, arduino, atmega

Trying to build a menu system but running into some issues with pointers - which I don't have much experience with.

I don't understand why removing the while(1) makes the comparison fail between mainmenu_table[1][i] == &option6 but for some reason it does.

What am I doing wrong?  Using visual studio and an atmega328p.  Thanks

Serial output with original code:

```
Serial begins
MeNu6
MeNu6
Starting compare loop
it worked
```

Serial output with while(1) removed.

```
Serial begins
MeNu6
MeNu6
Starting compare loop
the end
```

Original code (with while(1) included)

```
const char option1[] PROGMEM = "Menu1";
const char option2[] PROGMEM = "MEnu2";
const char option3[] PROGMEM = "MeNu3";

const char option4[] PROGMEM = "Menu4";
const char option5[] PROGMEM = "MEnu5";
const char option6[] PROGMEM = "MeNu6";
const char option7[] PROGMEM = "menu7";

const char* const submenu1_table[] PROGMEM = { option1, option2, option3 }; // array of pointers to chars stored in flash
const char* const submenu2_table[] PROGMEM = { option4, option5, option6, option7 };
const char** const mainmenu_table[] PROGMEM = { submenu1_table, submenu2_table }; //array of pointers to pointers to chars in flash


// The setup() function runs once each time the micro-controller starts
void setup()
{

    Serial.begin(9600);
    delay(100);
    Serial.println("Serial begins");  

    Serial.println((const __FlashStringHelper*)(mainmenu_table[1][2]));  // prints "Menu6" as expected
    Serial.println((const __FlashStringHelper*)option6);  // also prints "Menu6"

    Serial.println("Starting compare loop");

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if ( mainmenu_table[1][i] == &option6 ) { //
            Serial.println("it worked");
            while (1);  // COMMENTING THIS OUT MEANS DOESN'T COMPARE SUCCESSFULLY.
        }
    }

    Serial.println("the end");

}

// Add the main program code into the continuous loop() function
void loop()
{

}
```

Comment: Is `Serial.println` a standard function in C++? You have no includes so where is it defined?

Comment: @usr2564301 It is the Arduino standard library.

Comment: Thanks @walnut that is correct

Comment: First of, `while (1);` is not allowed. Infinite loops that do not eventually access either IO, volatiles, or atomics have undefined behavior in C++.

Comment: Can you try compiling this will all optimization turned off? I wonder if Arduino optimizes out naked Serial.println commands?

Comment: Second, the type of `mainmenu_table` is wrong. It should not compile in standard-C++. If I remember correctly Arduino uses `-fpermissive` by-default, which is a terrible idea. The type should be `const char* const* const`.

Comment: I've turned off optimization in visual studio - I am using the visual micro plugin - I don't think this has additional optimization.  After turning off visual studio optimisation ("No optimisation"), the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks @walnut I will change the type now

Comment: Similarly `&option6` does not have the correct type either and would fail to compile without `-fpermissive`. The type of `&option6` is `const char (*)[6]`, not `const char*` as you expect. I have no idea how GCC with `-fpermissive` behaves in such cases. But to write standard-C++ you need to remove the `&`. The array decays to a pointer to the first element by itself. This may or may not be the cause of your issue.

Comment: So try `if ( mainmenu_table[1][i] == option6 ) {`

Comment: Unfortunately after changing the type of mainmenu_table and also trying ( mainmenu_table[1][i] == option6 )  it still only works if I include the while(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Arduino description of [PROGMEM](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/), you cannot access the data through  pointers to it directly as with plain pointers. You need to use the [proper macros/functions](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html) to access the data.

In your code, the pointer tables themselves are located in the PROGMEM, so, to extract the individual pointers, you are supposed to do something like:

```
const char** submenu = (const char**)pgm_read_word(&(mainmenu_table[1]));
const char* option = (const char*)pgm_read_word(&(submenu[i]));
if (option == option6) {
    //...
```

This code is based on the string table example from the first link.